# gdal_array crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

I have problem with python in QGIS. A module I have installed (AROSICS if it matters) uses a gdal_array.OpenNumPyArray function. It however crashes my QGIS when I try to run a script including functions from AROSICS. I have tracked down the error to the function and below is the (not)working example, which crashes QGIS when run from python console:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal_array

array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) # a test array
ds = gdal_array.OpenNumPyArray(array) # command, which crashes QGIS
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 on Lenovo Y580 and QGIS 2.18.11 installed, alongside everything else (python, gdal, bindings...) with the newest version of OSGEO4W installer.
The problem persists after a reinstall of QGIS and on a completely different machine running Windows 10, so I assume it's something within GDAL. From a research on the net I got to know, that I should have a _gdal_array.pyd file somewhere in the installation and I do, however a _gdal_array.dll is missing. Is it important? What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: I have same your problem, Did you install latest version of gdal?

Comment: Honestly I, gave up and installed Ubuntu on a second partition for the sole task of running AROSICS. It works there.